# Abstracting Data in Context to deal with future object type (Strategy design pattern)?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have to design a data validation framework, which basically breaks down in these components.

1. Data Accessors - what's the best way
   to deal with this
2. Object Builders -
       how should I prepare for future
       object structures
3. Validators (Strategy Pattern)

I have to apply some rules on data, but I don't know what that data set would be like in future.

**So I am confused after a lot of thinking whether Rules should know about how the object looks like or is it possible without Rule and data being dependent** (I have a feel that, yes it is but don't know how). I am finding it hard to design abstraction for dataset.

any clues, in what direction I should think?

language - C# (.NET)
platform - Windows

**EDIT:** exact question

**in Stratagy pattern, is it possible that Context can hold generic object and strategy can deal with that, without knowing how the object is constructed ?**

Comment: Regarding your flag, I'm sure this might be of some use to someone in the future.

Answer (score 2):

In a validation framework, you usually have a set of "out-of-the-box" rules that don't know anything about what the object/entity looks like. For example, you might have a NotNullRule to check a given property is not null:

```
//code is not REAL code!

var user = new User({username=null, email="hello@test.com");
var notNullrule = new NotNullRule( typeof(User).GetProperty("username"), user );
var errors = notNullrule.Check();
Debug.Assert( errors[0] == "Property Username cannot be null");
```

It's common to use attributes to setup which validation strategy to use on which properties of a class. See [this example here](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/05/01/nhibernate-validator.aspx).

Validation frameworks usually let you create custom rules too, that might be domain specific. For example:

```
public class CustomerIsEligibleForDiscount : Rule
{ 
    public void Check(){ ... }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you define an abstract/base class that calls an abstract ValidateRules() method when necessary, then you can implement ValidateRules() within each class that inherits from the abstract/base class.

Declaring the method as abstract in the base class enforces its implementation in any derived class.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you can't use one of the many existing C# Validation Frameworks as a starting point?  They tend to have conventions built in for handling these concerns.

- http://validationframework.codeplex.com/
- http://xval.codeplex.com/
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480193.aspx
- http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs